# Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (784, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I try to train a model on the mnist dataset. Here, `features` and `targets` are two pandas Dataframe extracted from a csv file.
I initiate the dataset using tensorflow:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, targets))
```

Each line is a set of 784 integers, one value for each cell of the image.
In this case, the tf dataset looks like this:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]], shape=(6271, 784), dtype=int64)
```

Then I try to use the following model

```
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(784, 1))
input_flat = layers.Flatten()(input_layer)
middle_layer = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_flat)
output_layer = layers.Dense(10)(middle_layer)
model = Model(input_layer, output_layer)

******************************************
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 784, 1)]          0         
                                                               
flatten (Flatten)           (None, 784)               0         
                                                               
dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               100480    
                                                               
dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                1290      
                                                               
=================================================================
```

And I get this error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model' (type Functional).

Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (784, 1)

Call arguments received by layer 'model' (type Functional):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(784,), dtype=int64)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

I can't figure out what part of the model has a wrong dimension. Any idea how to fix it?